# Trying to erase a ScriptDb database that is faulty due to my error

Tags: google-apps-script

Quite embarrassing really, but I tested creating a database from a spreadsheet with a modified script from [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#copying_a_spreadsheet_into_the_database):

```
function loadDatabaseFromSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my_key').getSheetByName('Payroll');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data = data.splice(0, 9);                 // **this is where I went wrong**
  var keys = data[0];                       // **this actually corresponds with a blank row**
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var rowData = data[row];
    var item = {};
    for (var column = 0; column < keys.length; column++) {
      item[keys[column]] = rowData[column]; // **null values used to name attributes???**
    }
    db.save(item);
  }
}
```

So the Javascrit noob should have used `data.splice(0, 9)` rather than `data = data.splice(0, 9)`.  I wanted to remove the first nine rows from the array, not retain them.

Anyway, it seems as it stands the database is not repairable or erasable.  I can't retrieve any records; any time I try to invoke .next() or .hasNext() I get a server error thrown, for example with this script from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#deleting_all_items_from_the_database):

```
function deleteAll() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  while (true) {
    var result = db.query({}); // get everything, up to limit
    if (result.getSize() == 0) {
      break;
    }
    while (result.hasNext()) {
      db.remove(result.next());
    }
  }
}
```

.getSize() does work, but the script returns a server error when it gets to the line with .hasNext(), presumably because of the faulty object.  I also tried a batch remove:

```
function batchRemove() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var result = db.query({});
  db.removeBatch(result, false); 
}
```

And I get:

> Cannot find method removeBatch($Proxy799,boolean). (line 114)

By the way, I can successfully save a new record to the database, and retrieve that record with a query, but if the query returns anything else in the database that was created with the flawed script, that's when I get the failure when I try to work with the resulting objects.

So I understand my error and promise to take more care in the future, but does anyone know how I can "clean out" my database to start again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK false alarm I guess, I tried again and I'm able to clear the database now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was not a false alarm, I have experienced similar behaviour when a function that operates over a ScriptDb exceeds the execution time. The ScriptDb becomes unresponsive when you try to delete, or interact somehow with the objects affected with the execution time error. It seems all you can do is wait, and then everything goes back to normal. 
The best practice is to establish strategies to prevent that  the functions interacting with ScriptDb's, ever reach the execution time limit.